# Drag and drop not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, native

I have implemented drag and drop using Native HTML5 drag and drop.
It works fine in IE11.It works in chrome and Firefox too.
But fails in IE7.I cant find what the problem is.
Is there any solution for this???

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.box {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid #0092BF;
  background-color: #FFEBDD;
  margin-right: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
img:hover { cursor:move}
</style>

<body>
<div id="boxes-example">
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" draggable="false" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>A</header>
        <p>
        order!
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>B</header>
        <p>
        Put me
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>C</header>
        <p>
        right
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>D</header>
        <p>
        into
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>E</header>
        <p>
        the
        </p>
    </div>
</div>



 <script>
    (function () {
        var id_ = 'boxes-example';
        var boxes_ = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id_ + ' .box');
        var dragSrcEl_ = null;

        this.handleDragStart = function (e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

            dragSrcEl_ = this;

            this.style.opacity = '0.5';

            // this/e.target is the source node.
            this.addClassName('moving');
        };

        this.handleDragOver = function (e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Allows us to drop.
            }

            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

            return false;
        };

        this.handleDragEnter = function (e) {
            this.addClassName('over');
        };

        this.handleDragLeave = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is previous target element.

            this.removeClassName('over');
        };

        this.handleDrop = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is current target element.

            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
            }

            // Don't do anything if we're dropping on the same box we're dragging.
            if (dragSrcEl_ != this) {
                dragSrcEl_.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
            }

            return false;
        };

        this.handleDragEnd = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is the source node.
            this.style.opacity = '1';

            [ ].forEach.call(boxes_, function (box) {
                box.removeClassName('over');
                box.removeClassName('moving');
            });
        };

        [ ].forEach.call(boxes_, function (box) {
            box.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // Enable boxes to be draggable.
            box.addEventListener('dragstart', this.handleDragStart, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handleDragEnter, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handleDragLeave, false);
            box.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd, false);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: IE7 doesn't support HTML5.

Comment: Can you tell me which versions of IE support html5? @Miguel

Comment: HTML5 is roughly supported since IE9 and fully from IE10 I believe. In order to have fallbacks for other browsers or work arounds for HTML5 features, people use polyfills like [html5shiv](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv) , but in this case, since it's a javascript issue specifically I don't know how you would do it. I think the best solution is probably using drag and drop from older versions of jquery 1.x and jquery ui which are compatible with IE6+ .